# calculate number of days between two days in sqlserver?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to calculate the number of days an employee has taken leave in the month of january.For that I have two date fields Leave_Start_Date and Leave_End_Date in the database as follows

```
Leave_Approval_Id      Leave_Start_Date           Leave_End_Date             EmpId 
    1               2013-01-25 00:00:00.000      2013-02-10 00:00:00.000      10
```

Here my problem is the Leave_End_Date is on february.So when i take the datedifference im getting the value as 16,but acctually i want is 6(in the month of january alone).

How can i do it ???

Comment: datediff()............. A function used in the answer to another of your questions....

Comment: I have used datediff() function and im getting the result as 16,since the days in february is also taken.

Answer (score 1):

Define the interval you are interested in and use a `case` to use the range values or your actual values as parameters to `datediff()`.

```
declare @FromDate datetime
declare @ToDate datetime

set @FromDate = '20130101'
set @ToDate = '20130131'

select datediff(
                day, 
                case when Leave_Start_Date < @FromDate then @FromDate else Leave_Start_Date end,
                case when Leave_End_Date >= @ToDate then @ToDate else Leave_End_Date end
               )
from ....
```

This will give you `6` for the interval you specified.